# Using a list view to filter another list view

Tags: list-view, xslt, filter, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have two lists; List A and List B. List B has a lookup column to List A.

I want to filter List B based on the value in the field that looks up A. This can of course be done using the default OOTB column filtering. However, I want to create a view/webpart that does this for me using URL filters. Since List A will change from time to time, I won't hardcode the URL's, I want to create a special filtering view of List A I can add to List B's view.

I've managed to do what I'm trying except for one issue. When I filter List B using URL filters (e.g. http://server/site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=DocumentID&FilterValue1=650) it will filter both List A's and List B's views simultaneously. I only want the filtering to be applied to List B. The solution to this could be to add View as an URL attribute, e.g. ?View={GUID}&FilterField1=DocumentID&FilterValue1=650. This will work, but then I need a reference to the View ID of List B from my List A xslt (to apply to the URLs).

Frankly, I could even live with the GUIDs being hardcoded, e.g. that I set them in List B's CAML and in the XSLT of List A. However, they just don't "stick", they are overridden during deployment.

Another option could be to render List A as "unfilterable". if you have any suggestions I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "Filters » Query String (URL) Filter" webpart on a custom page.

Comment: I don't have an enterprise licence